# How to reverse a array without use of Reverse function and length of code should be 28 at max?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I tried lot of ways to reverse it, but my length of code is 72 or 68 max, which I was able to get. Is there any best way to reduce it further.

```
//First Function - 67 is the length
reverse=(a)=>{return a.reduceRight((c,b)=>{return c.concat(b)},[])}

//Second trial- 72 

reverse=(a)=>{
var r=[],i=a.length;
while(i-->0){r.push(a.pop())}
 return r}
```

Comment: i have seen the question yesterday ...

Comment: @NinaScholz Me too :-)

Comment: Why you need `=>{return a.` when you could just `=>a.`